# matplotlib background color gradient produces boundary

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want the white background of my plot to blend in with a gradient and have that color gradient fill the right half of the plot starting at some x-value.
I am doing this by inserting a color gradient into the background of a matplotlib plot using `imshow` and using a seaborn color palette for the gradient.

However, if I do this using the below code, I get a slight mismatch between the lightest color in my palette (which I expect to be white) and the white of the plot background.

```
 ax.imshow(
    [[0, 1], [0, 1]],
    interpolation="bicubic",
    cmap=sns.cubehelix_palette(start=0, rot=0, hue=0, light=1, dark=0.7, as_cmap=True,),
    extent=(x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max),
    alpha=1,
    aspect="auto",
)
```

The problem is the same with

```
cmap=sns.color_palette("blend:#FFFFFF,#C1C1C1", as_cmap=True)
```

The difference is subtle but noticable as seen from the attached image.
How can I resolve this and match the two colors?
[image]

Comment: `interpolation="bicubic"` does some extrapolation when only two values are given.  Did you try with `interpolation="bilinear"`?

Comment: If you do `colormap = sns.cubehelix_palette(start=0, rot=0, hue=0, light=1, dark=0.7, as_cmap=True)` and `print(colormap(0.0))` you get exactly white (`(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)`). Your issue is not related to seaborn, but to the way `imshow()` works with bicubic interpolation.

Comment: you are right, this was indeed the issue. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`interpolation="bicubic"` does some extrapolation when only two values are given. Instead, you can use `interpolation="bilinear"`.

To get the interpolation of the cubic curve, you could change the `[[0, 1], [0, 1]]` to a cubic function.

Here is some code that extracts the pixel values for each case, and shows them as a curve.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=2, sharey='row', figsize=(15, 6))
for i, interp in enumerate(['bicubic', 'bilinear', 'bilinear']):
    if i < 2:
        gradient = [[0, 1], [0, 1]]
    else:
        x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
        gradient = ((3 - 2 * x) * x * x).reshape(1, -1)
    img = axs[0, i].imshow(gradient,
                           interpolation=interp,
                           cmap=sns.cubehelix_palette(start=0, rot=0, hue=0, light=1, dark=0.7, as_cmap=True),
                           extent=[0, 1, 0, 1],
                           alpha=1, aspect="auto")
    axs[0, i].set_title(f'interpolation={interp} {"linear" if i < 2 else "cubic"} gradient')
    axs[0, i].set_xticks([])
    axs[0, i].set_yticks([])

    # show the color value of the central row as a curve
    data = img.make_image(renderer=None)[0]  # get image data as a numpy NxMx4 array
    values = data[data.shape[0] // 2, :, :3].mean(axis=1)  # get central row and average r, g and b
    axs[1, i].step(np.arange(len(values)), values, color='dodgerblue')
    axs[1, i].axhline(255, color='red', ls='--')
    axs[1, i].text(len(values), 255, "\n255 (100% white) ", color='red', va='center', ha='right')
    axs[1, i].set_title(f'start pixel: {values[0]:.0f}')
    axs[1, i].margins(x=0)
axs[1, 0].set_ylabel('color values')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plt.imshow: comparing pixel values for bicubic vs bilinear interpolation]